# What is the runtime complexity?

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, complexity-theory

```
F(x, y, k, targetX, targetY) {

if (x==targetX && y=targetY && k==0)

   return 1;

stepsLeft = (targetX-x) + (targetY-y);

if (k<stepsLeft)

   return 0;

return F(x+1, y, k-1, targetX, targetY) + 

            F(x-1, y, k-1, targetX, targetY) + 

            F(x, y-1, k-1, targetX, targetY) + 

            F(x, y+1, k-1,targetX, targetY);
```

It should be a dynamic programing recursion, the idea is to get from 0,0 to any coordinate and I can only move one step at a time.
I need to count the amount of different ways to get there